# Text without opacity within a container with opacity

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a `img` with a black overlay. The overlay has an `opacity` and a white text within. When I hover the wrapper, a red overlay with a different `opacity` and text is visible. It works all fine. My only issue is, to remove the `opacity` on the text within the overlays. The text is white, but also transparent. How can I manage it, to put the text within a transparent container without transparent effect on the letters/text? I know, if I put the text out of this box and style it a in the center id would work. But I'd like to have the text element within the transparent container. Hope this is clear enough. Any ideas?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay-black {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.overlay-red {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .overlay-black {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .overlay-red {
  display: flex;
}

h2,
p {
  color: white;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay overlay-black">
    <h2>Yoda</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay overlay-red">
    <p>May the force be with you!</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://digitalspyuk.cdnds.net/16/38/768x403/gallery-1474472774-yoda-008.jpg" alt="testpic">
</div>
```

Comment: you could use an rgba colour for the background so you don't need to set opacity: eg `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4)` would be a black black background with 0.4 opacity - more info: https://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Comment: @Pete perfekt, works fine -  thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the key part is:

```
.overlay-black {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

Please see below snippet I believe/hope this is what you expected.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay-black {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.overlay-red {
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .overlay-black {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper:hover .overlay-red {
  display: flex;
}

h2,
p {
  color: white;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay overlay-black">
    <h2>Yoda</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay overlay-red">
    <p>May the force be with you!</p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://digitalspyuk.cdnds.net/16/38/768x403/gallery-1474472774-yoda-008.jpg" alt="testpic">
</div>
```

Comment: (Ah, @Pete was quicker in comments. I'll leave it here though for the Run snippet feature)

Comment: That's nice, thanks :)